# Cannot reply to multiple senders and accept shared calendar in Outlook 2010

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2010

Cannot reply to multiple senders and accept shared callendar in Outlook 2010.

The Error message is:

> Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action.

It is online and I can reply to a single sender. Server is Exchange 2003. 
And of course I can reply to multiple senders in OWA, so it is not server problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try redownloading the address book. It seems like Outlook 2010 is more prone to corruption.

Comment: Looks like you found the source of the problem. I cannot download Global Address Book. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Try... "Send/Receive" tab and then "Download Address Book..." from the "Send/Receive Groups" pull-down...

Comment: Also delete the .OST and start over with a new one as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would delete all offline files or run this command at a command prompt:

`del "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost"`

It will delete the offline files. Like user48838 said above, Outlook is prone to corruption of these files and it causes a lot of issues.